# Banach tori: classification up to Fréchet homeomorphisms

Tags: banach-spaces, banach-manifold, frechet-manifold, banach-lattices, homeomorphism

Consider the set $T$ in $l_p$ defined as closure of

\begin{equation}
T = \{ (x_1,\dotsc,x_n,\dotsc): x_j = \frac{1}{2^{(j/p)}} e^{it_j}, t_j \in \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z} \}.
\end{equation}

This seems to be a good analogue of a finite dimensional torus.

Q1: What is the topology of this space?

By Kadec theorem, all separable Banach spaces are homeomorphic. Thus, up to homeomorphism, it would seem reasonable to expect that there is only one Banach torus.

But then suppose that we would like to restrict somewhat the "size" of the the homeomorphism.

Q2: Does this lead to "Fréchet tori" that are distinct (within a more restrictive notion of homeomorphism, i.e. "Fréchet homeomorphism")?

Comment: Please use $j$ as an index instead of $i$!!!!!!!

Comment: Could you clarify what is meant by "topology" in Q1? The trivial answer is that the topology is the subspace topology induced from $l_p$. Did you mean to ask about the homeomorphism type of $T$? Incidentally, two separable Frechet manifolds are homeomorphic if and only if they are homotopy equivalent.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek By "topology"  I mean in this case computation of homotopy and homology groups. If I understand correctly, they are homeomorphic if we do not restrict the norm of the homeomorphism. For example, Banach spheres are not contractible by 1+compact contractions.